# Who needs to join the Apple MFi program?

Tags: ios-appstore, bluetooth, developer-program, accessories, ios

Company X is developing Bluetooth speakers. We outsource our electronic chips from company Y and I'm working on developing a Bluetooth enabled app.

Will the app get disapproved by Apple if the company X is not a part of the [Apple MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Is the company X creating a generic Bluetooth speaker or a hardware that interfaces with propritory Apple technologies (such as HomeKit or AirPlay)? Is the company X planning to market the hardware as Made for iPhone/iPad/iPod touch?

Comment: Not a generic product more like e.g JBL but in very early stages and neither will it interface with apple's proprietary services. Marketing as Made for iPhone... not necessarily but is stating on the packaging, "download the app for the speaker from app store" be consequential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company that plans to market the end product that carries the MiFi certification is responsible for obtaining that certification.

There’s no expectation that every component on the BOM be manufactured in house.  You have to submit product designs, plans, specifications and even packaging before you begin manufacturing.  Then you must submit samples for both mechanical and electrical testing to ensure that it complies.

Do you need MiFi certification?

No.  You can develop products that have apps that provide their functionality be available via the App Store and not be MiFi certified.  One good example would be Bose.  They market headphones as “Apple Version” or “Android Version” with an app in the App store and there’s no MiFi certification.  Notice that the quoted text is not “Made for iPhone” (or similar).  To say that, would require MiFi certification.

Regarding your specific situation, the [FAQ](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#3-1) provides answers:

> **I want to develop an accessory that communicates with an Apple device using only Bluetooth Low Energy. Do I need to join the MFi Program?**
>
> No. Accessories which connect to an Apple device using only Bluetooth Low Energy/BLE/Bluetooth 4.0 or standard Bluetooth profiles supported by iOS are not part of the MFi Program.

> **I want to develop an iOS app that communicates with an MFi accessory. Do I need to join the MFi Program?**
>
> No. iOS app developers do not need to join the MFi Program. Everything app developers need is in the External Accessory Framework, which is provided in the iOS SDK.

Comment: In addition, this is a hardware certification and not software.

Comment: @Allan, concerning the last FAQ you referenced it says "...that communicates with an MFi accessory...", though our product is not MFi licensed. And if you check here https://bit.ly/2AGeVva Bose has the MFi license based on the apple stickers so I'm not quiet sure

Comment: And by Bluetooth, I mean Classic Bluetooth. 

Can I conclude that what you mean is that what our company will be doing is not recommended by Apple, though it'll work (gray area)? Because there's so much online content saying MFi is a requirement.

Comment: Bose was a bad example because they have a cable that attaches.  The Soundlink is a better example than the QC products.  The link I put there says as an iOS dev even if you connect to a MIFi device you don’t need to join the program to submit your app.

Comment: No gray area.  It’s not limited to “classic” bluetooth.  BLE, BT4.O, and any standard profile, you’re in the clear.